# Is there a way to position a bootstrap modal popup in iframe near the clicked button?

Tags: iframe, bootstrap-modal

I am using an iframe to display a php page. I used a script within the iframe that sizes it to the documents height. This allows the user to scroll the main window without having dual scroll bars on the page. I am using a bootstrap modal within the iframe to display an image. The issue is that when clicked the modal popup is displayed at the top center of the iframe. However if the user had to scroll down the list prior to clicking the 'show image' button, they wont find the popup unless they know to scroll all the way back to the top.

I have searched relentlessly for a solution to this within this site and google with no clear understandable answer. Hoping one of you experts can enlighten me.

Here is my modal code:

```
 <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <img id="img" src="" width="100%" >
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the script:

```
<script>

$(document).on('click', '.getinfoBtn', function(e){
var image=$(this).attr('data-image');
$('#img').attr('src', image);
return false;
});

</script>
```

Here is the iframe script used to get height of content to be displayed:

```
<iframe id="form-iframe" src="rooz/on-tap.php" style="margin-top:20px; width:100%; height:150px; border:none; overflow:hidden;" scrolling="no" onload="AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad()"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">
function AdjustIframeHeightOnLoad() { document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = document.getElementById("form-iframe").contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight + "px"; }
function AdjustIframeHeight(i) { document.getElementById("form-iframe").style.height = parseInt(i) + "px"; }
</script>
```

As stated previously, this code works but pops up the image at the top center of the iframe. I would really like it to either pop up near the button clicked or at least visible.

Comment: Is this not possible? I am surprised that I have not  received even one response.

Comment: Instead of a modal, could I make the image that the modal would have shown a tooltip? Is that possible?

Comment: Or possibly open the modal in the parent window instead of inside the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Bootstrap 3.4, what I could make is to catch the `show.bs.modal` event and setup its position according the click. To avoid the glitch effect, I hide the modal and show it after move it.
I didn't find the way to parametrize the modal in its creation to set it up, instead of enforce it.

```
$('#theModalDiv').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
    const modalWidth = 600; // Because #attendeesModal has no lg nor sm size
                            // and by default, bootstrap modals has 600px width
    const target = $(event.relatedTarget);
    let newLeft = (document.getElementById('iframe-content-body').offsetWidth/2) - (modalWidth); // Centering the modal
    const modal = $(this); // Getting modal instance
    modal.css('opacity', '0'); // Hidding modal

    // After some time...
    setTimeout(() => {
        modal.offset({
            // ...setting new modal position
            ...target.offset(),
            left: newLeft,
        });

        // ...setting same top position as the click
        $('.modal-dialog').css('margin-top', 0);

        // ...displaying again the modal
        modal.css('opacity', '1');
    }, 500); // This value was taken with rule of thumb
});
```

I hope someone can find this usefull.